# How to pass specific parameters to Azure Resource Template?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I'm using Azure Resource Template to create a `Microsoft.Web/connections` resource type.
Here is the relevant resource contained in the template :

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/connections",
  "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
  "name": "azurequeues",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "kind": "V1",
  "properties": {
    "displayName": "[parameters('queue-storage-name')]",
    "api": {
      "id": "[concat('/subscriptions/', parameters('subscription-id') ,'/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/', resourceGroup().location, '/managedApis/', 'azurequeues')]"
    },
    "customParameterValues": {}
  }
},
```

The resource gets deployed correctly but when I get to the portal I see the following error :

[image: Error on azure]

The error disappears when I manually enter the missing informations in the following form :

[image]

My question is : **How can I pass those informations directly in the resource template ?**

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. `Azure Resource Template` uses the Azure Resource Rest Api's to provision the resources on the cloud.

I found [this article](https://www.bruttin.com/2017/06/13/deploy-logic-app-with-arm.html) talking about `Logic Apps & API connectors using ARM` that points out to [this tool](https://github.com/projectkudu/ARMClient) which provides you with the parameters the API call would allow.

My resource templates now looks like this :

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/connections",
  "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
  "name": "azurequeues",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "kind": "V1",
  "properties": {
    "displayName": "[parameters('queue-storage-name')]",
    "api": {
      "id": "[concat('/subscriptions/', parameters('subscription-id') ,'/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/', resourceGroup().location, '/managedApis/', 'azurequeues')]"
    },
    "parameterValues": {
      "storageaccount": "[parameters('storage-account-name')]",
      "sharedkey": "[parameters('storage-account-shared-key')]"
    }
  }
}
```